# Importing LESS CSS Files with variables

Tags: css, less

I have 2 LESS CSS files called core.less and style.less

core.less is located under: \css\core.less and its contents are below:

```
body {
    background: @bg_color;
    color: @font_color;
}
```

style.less is located under: \css\green\style.less and its contents are below:

```
@bg_color: #0F0;
@font_color: #FFF;
@import "../../core.less";
```

The **core.less** file contains all the css rules, in LESS format, but does not provide the definitions for the variables.

The **style.less** defines all the variables referenced in core.less, and then imports the core.less file.

I have no problems compiling style.less as it imports all the rules from the core file. The core.less file cannot be compiled - it will generate errors since it does not contain the variable definitions.

I would now like to compile the **core.css** file as well (just to make sure there are no errors in my LESS rules). Is there any way of adding some kind of dummy/placeholder variables in the core.less file such that it can also be complied without generating errors and still work with the setup I have explained above?

I am open to suggestions on changing the format / structure of the files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By importing **core.less** into **style.less** you **are** compiling the "LESS rules" of core.less.

Comment: You're 100% correct - I can't believe I didnt think of that before. I just introduced some errors into core.less and it failed straight away - so no need to change anything on my part. Thanks for taking time to answer.

Comment: No worries. Takes a bit to wrap your head around importing and compiling :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should not define variables, needed in `core.less`, outside of `core.less`. I typically make "core" files (in any programming language, really) have no dependencies on the rest of the code.

Comment: Im not quite sure I follow your suggestion Matt. Are you saying keep the variables out of core.less? I have a bunch of different style files that all call up core.less, each one of the style files only defines the variables, and then imports core.less - so core does have to contain the variables, as i see it.