# Can we have variable in css which passes dynamic value

Tags: css, variables, less

i am using /color.less which holds all the colors in my application and i am using main.less where i include this which works perfectly fine using lesscss [less.js]. now i will have different color theming with theme1/color.less and have n number of themes. can we have a variable included in the main.less which includes the relative path of the color file.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532754/importing-less-css-files-with-variables

Answer (score 0):

Use different css classes and set the class to use dynamically.